# I am not able to connect my python program using mysqldb with lampp server

Tags: python, mysql, server, mysql-python, lampp

I am able to connect my Python program with lampp server using mysqldb as `host="localhost"` but as soon as change `host="myIPaddress"` it is showing errors for sql queries.

This is working fine:

```
database=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="TextMiner",unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")
```

But this is showing error:

```
database=MySQLdb.connect(host="myIPaddress",user="root",passwd="",db="TextMiner",unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")
```

Error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myIPaddress' (110)")

Comment: Your mysql-server is listening only the localhost interface. Change bind-address in mysql configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql security settings. 
Must be set to local only.

Comment: How to check  that??

Comment: After running lampp I am able to open the index.php page using http://localhost but showing error for http://myIPaddress